# Trigger function on a certain element - ngrepeat - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Good morning,

I'm trying to change the limitTo filter on a certain list, my issue is:
when I click to the trigger who change the filter limit the filter changes on all ng-repeated categories.

my function inside the main controller

```
$scope.showMore = function(limit) {

  if($scope.limitItems === $scope.itemsPerList) {
        $scope.limitItems = limit;
        $scope.switchFilterText = 'less';
  } else {
        $scope.switchFilterText = 'more';
        $scope.limitItems = $scope.itemsPerList;
  }


}
```

my scenario (I rewrote it in a simplified version)

```
<li ng-repeat="item in category.items | limitTo: limitItems ">
    {{item.title}}
</li>
<li ng-if="limitItems < (category.items.length)">
   <a ng-click="showMore(category.items.length)" >Show {{ switchFilterText }}</a>
</li>
```

Could you explain me what's wrong with me?
I searched how to select a single element to apply the function but I didn't find anything useful

**Update**:

I found the way to solve my issue in this way:
No functions inside the controller are involved to make this functionality works properly:

```
<li ng-repeat="category in maincategories" ng-init="limitItems = maxItemsPerList">
{{category.title}}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in category.items | limitTo: limitItems ">   {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
<a ng-click="limitItems = category.items.length" href>
    <b ng-if="category.items.length > maxItemsPerList && limitItems != category.items.length "> Show more </b>
</a>
```

I'm not really convinced about Angular (I used it in my past and I was impressed by the performance but now I can see logics senseless):

**What I learned:**

ng-if and ng-click cannot be used in the same content because ng-if creates new scopes so if you put ng-if on top of the "show more" link it will break the code

ng-init cannot be used in the same element of the ng-repeat otherwise the var initialised will not be available inside the ng-repeat block

I think there is another way to do that, maybe more clean but in this specific case I can't do a lot.

Comment: u mean ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end - so u can use $index?

Comment: ng-click is outside the ng-repeat loop so $index is meaningless.
$index (even though it's meaningless) isn't used by `showMore()` anyway, so you might as well remove it.

Comment: I'm not using index, I just like to know how can I trigger the showMore functionality on a certain element inside a ng-repeat.

ex:

repeated elements:

- el1
- el2
- el3
- el4

i would like to apply the showmore function on el3 only.
The current code triggers showmore function on el1, el2, el3,el4

Comment: It looks like you're repeating on category.items but your click passes country.item. Is that just a typo here or in tour code?

Comment: sry @JohnNiedzwiecki ... I'll fix the question.. it was just an example, the code is correct I just simplified it on the question.

Anyway, I solved the problem by myself in a different way... I'm going to explain it at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

> ng-if and ng-click cannot be used in the same content because ng-if
>   creates new scopes so if you put ng-if on top of the "show more" link
>   it will break the code

Yes, ng-if creates a new scope, but it is possible to mix ng-if and ng-click (and most other directives). To do that, you'll be safer if you always write to atributes of another object instead of a simple variable. It is plain JavaScript prototypal inheritance in play.

```
<li ... ng-init="category.limitItems = maxItemsPerList">
```

> ng-init cannot be used in the same element of the ng-repeat otherwise
>   the var initialised will not be available inside the ng-repeat block

True, in the sense that variables are created in the local scope. But again, refer to an object.

> I think there is another way to do that, maybe more clean but in this
>   specific case I can't do a lot.

You don't need to do a lot, it is quite simple to do it right actually.

Some advices:

- Use ng-init with care. I know it will tempt us but always try to put logic inside controllers and services;
- Avoid assignments inside templates;
- Learn how to use controllerAs syntax. It gives you an object to write your models to (*the controller*), so solves most problems related to scope inheritance;
- Do not inject $scope, put your view models inside controllers.

Full code goes like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="category in maincategories" ng-init="category.limitItems = maxItemsPerList">
{{category.title}}
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in category.items | limitTo: category.limitItems ">   {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
<a ng-if="category.items.length > maxItemsPerList && category.limitItems != category.items.length" ng-click="category.limitItems = category.items.length" href>
    <b> Show more </b>
</a>
```